# Problema al conectarme con websocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, websocket

Así es la configuración en mi implementación del socket, intenté habilitar el acceso a todos los origines pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error, aquí dejo el código:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class ConfiguracionSocket implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/tema");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(
            "/notificaciones",
            "/chat"
    );
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/socket/v1").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
 }
}
```

Y este el código de error que experimento cuando intento conectarme

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)' of interface org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource
```

Estas son mis dependencias relacionadas con el websocket:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.14.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.14.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Por favor, incluye tu configuración de dependencias (maven o gradle) para validar si tienes algún mismatch

Comment: @Alfabravo por favor mira nuevamente la publicación, ya coloqué las dependencias relacionadas

Comment: Hm, no sé si tienes esto en un spring boot. Revisa si la versión de spring boot es compatible con spring framework 5.2.14

Comment: @Alfabravo <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/>

Comment: En ese caso deberías usar     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Comment: @GavilanPatagonico o sea, debo borrar la dependecia que ya tengo de websocket y colocar esta nueva?

Comment: Claro, y creo que también la de spring messaging. Si tenes dudas generate un proyecto nuevo con Spring Initializr(https://start.spring.io/) y mirá cómo queda el pom.